# W3C validator reports "Stray end tag ’html’"

Tags: html, validation

I'm baffled at what could be causing the validator error on this page as there's not a lot on this page. The error is on the <html> tag, I get a "Stray end tag `html`" message. What's wrong?

[http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.neurologicclinic.net&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.neurologicclinic.net&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: The link is broken, that is, to www.neurologicclinic.net (thus this problem can not be reproduced).

Answer (score 1):

The `<html></html>` tags should wrap all of the HTML content, including the `head` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You open an `<html>` tag after you already had your `<head>` section. This is invalid. The general order of those tags is as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an open `<html>` tag. It must go before `<head>`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

Comment: Rev 1 of the answer was neither critique nor a request for clarification. The `<html>` was present in the code but in the wrong position (See validation, with show source). I merely provided the correct position of this tag.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `<html>` tag should be defined above the `<head>` section, not after it.

e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   ..
  </head>
  <body>
  ..
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Such a noob mistake. Thanks!

Comment: In case of the `<html>` tag defined above the `<head>` section, the validator message would be *"Stray start tag `html`"*. Or maybe the validator changed in the past 6 years.